# Super/Krazy Glue on Outdoor Gear

Tags: gear, maintenance, repairs

I currently use All Purpose Krazy Glue to repair pinch flats on my road bike inner tubes.  All it takes is one drop over the bite and it seals it perfectly, works every time and holds 95 PSI for weeks with no leaks!

Recently I lost a pull tab on the back of my LaSportiva trailrunners.  I figured I would Krazy Glue it back on however when the drop landed the shoe smoked, the fibres melted and turned rock hard as if they were burned, which is most likely what happened.

I am curious, does anyone know what Super/Krazy Glue is appropriate to use on fabrics if any?  I understand the re-attachment of the trail runner tab is a pretty ambitious task.  What I would really like to do is put a drop over a small tear in my winter gloves, attach new leather to the palm, small tear on tent...

Does anyone have success using Super/Krazy Glue on Fabrics/Outdoor Gear?

Comment: It sounds to me what you are looking for is foam-safe cyanoacrylate glue. Usually the foam-safe label means it won't damage most plastic products; I've used it successfully on a backpack strap without issues. Your local hobby store can hook you up, look for CA+ foam safe glue. Keep in mind it's hard when dry, however.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the helpful comment, I'll be picking some up and giving it a go!

Comment: Just crazy glued on a patch will let u know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From looking at the Crazy Glue Website and from reading what it can be used for on the packages, I wouldn't try it on fabric, especially synthetic things like a rain jacket.

There does appear to be a Crazy Glue for wood and leather. Check the website.
http://www.krazyglue.com/products/product.aspx?pc=KG821
Read the directions. I have used some other adhesive products and have had better results when I followed the directions. A friend who works as a chemist told me that millions of dollars are spent to develop these products. But, if consumers don't use them properly, they are not going to work. For example: Some adhesives need moisture/water to held them bond. I think they take oxygen from the water.

That is a really good idea for bike tire flats. Wish I knew about that when I did a lot of cycling.

Do some research on fabric glue. I have repaired some gloves using a trimmed iron-on patch and a bit of sewing. I have used Shoe Goo and their All Purpose Camping Goo on my hiking boot seams to fix splits. I taped the inside with Gorilla tape first to hold the split closed. Elmer's All Purpose Glue-All and Gorilla Glue are also good for some things. They worked on my boots, too. But, they aren't flexible when they dry. So, using them on my more flexible running shoes didn't work as well. The Shoe/All Purpose Goo worked better. Match the glue with what you are trying to fix and read directions.

Comment: Super Glue was designed for sports injuries, so I'd imagine it would work with leather. Your chemist friend was right in that the product was designed and tested to work in certain conditions, and will react horribly with others (like if you were to swallow it). I know that Crazy Glue will dissolve certain plastics and foams (it will leave large holes in styrofoam), but I'll bet there's an extensive list of dos and don'ts for crazy glue out there somewhere. This has something to do with the solvent used and is product specific.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Krazy glue web site](http://www.krazyglue.com/faq/)

> There are a few things Instant Krazy Glue® is not intended for use on
>   such as paper, foam, rear view mirrors, polyethylene, Teflon® or other
>   fluorocarbons.

From that list I'd basically say any form of plastic isn't going to get along. Lots of outdoor gear are effectively made from various forms of plastic so I would not apply it to anything you haven't tested first.

Bike inner tubes are latex.  According to that list Leather should be fine.